# Google Cloud Workflows - "ResourceLimitError" when doing HTTP requests in a loop

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

We are using GCP Workflows to do some API calls for status check every n second via `http.post` call.

Everything was fine till recently all of our workflows started failing with internal error:

```json
{"message":"ResourceLimitError: Memory usage limit exceeded","tags":["ResourceLimitError"]}
```

I found out, that when we are using `GET` with query params, it's failure happens a bit later than the same for `POST` and body.

Here is the testing workflow:

```yaml
main:
    steps:
        - init:
            assign: 
                - i: 0
                - body:
                    foo: 'thisismyhorsemyhorseisamazing'
        - doRequest:
            call: http.request
            args:
                url: https://{my-location-and-project-id}.cloudfunctions.net/workflow-test
                method: GET
                query: ${body}
            result: res
        - sleepForOneSecond:
            call: sys.sleep
            args:
                seconds: 1
        - logCounter:
            call: sys.log
            args:
                text: ${"Iteration - " + string(i)}
                severity: INFO
        - increaseCounter:
            assign:
                - i: ${i + 1}
        - checkIfFinished:
            switch:
                - condition: ${i < 500}
                  next: doRequest
            next: returnOutput
        - returnOutput:
            return: ${res.body}
```

It can do up to 37 requests with GET and 32 with POST and then execution stops with an error. And that numbers don't change.

For reference, Firebase function on POST and GET returns 200 with next JSON:

```json
{
  "bar": "thisismyhorsemyhorseisamazing",
  "fyz": [],
}
```

Any ideas what goes wrong there? I don't think that 64Kb quota for variables is exceeded there. It shouldn't be calculated as a sum of all assignments, should it?

Comment: was going to report same. I thought at first I reached the limit of 64k but after many tries I came to the same conclusion that there must be a bug in google-workflows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the product, I found this [Google tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/181291782), This issue was reported.

It is better continue over the public issue tracker.